# One unit test affects another

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest

I'm defining two functions:

In **mkgeometry_additions.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

MKMapRect MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(MKCoordinateRegion region);

MKCoordinateRegion MKCoordinateRegionForSouthWestAndNorthEast(CLLocationCoordinate2D sw, CLLocationCoordinate2D ne);
```

In **mkgeometry_additions.m** (.m, even though they're c functions)

```
MKMapRect MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(MKCoordinateRegion region)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = region.center;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = region.span;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeft =
        CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - span.latitudeDelta / 2.0,
                                   center.longitude - span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRight =
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - span.latitudeDelta / 2.0,
                               center.longitude - span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
    MKMapPoint mapPointTopLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(topLeft);
    MKMapPoint mapPointBottomRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(bottomRight);
    double width = mapPointTopLeft.x - mapPointBottomRight.x;
    double height = mapPointTopLeft.y - mapPointBottomRight.y;

    return MKMapRectMake(mapPointTopLeft.x, mapPointTopLeft.y, width, height);
}

MKCoordinateRegion MKCoordinateRegionForSouthWestAndNorthEast(CLLocationCoordinate2D sw, CLLocationCoordinate2D ne)
{
    MKCoordinateSpan span =
        MKCoordinateSpanMake(ne.latitude - sw.latitude, ne.longitude - sw.longitude);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeft = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(ne.latitude, sw.longitude);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(topLeft.latitude + span.latitudeDelta * 0.5, topLeft.longitude + span.longitudeDelta * 0.5);
    return MKCoordinateRegionMake(center, span);
}
```

That's pretty much the entirety of the two files.

In my unit test with XCTests:

```
- (void)testMKMapRectForCoordinateRegionAfterReverseConversion
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D fremont = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.54827, -121.98857);
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(fremont, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05));
    MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region);
    MKCoordinateRegion derivedRegion = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(mapRect);

    double accuracy = 0.0001;

    XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(region.center.latitude, derivedRegion.center.latitude,
                               accuracy, @"Latitude is equal");
    XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(region.center.longitude, derivedRegion.center.longitude,
                               accuracy, @"Latitude is equal");
    XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(region.span.latitudeDelta, derivedRegion.span.latitudeDelta,
                               accuracy, @"Latitude delta is equal");
    XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(region.span.longitudeDelta, derivedRegion.span.longitudeDelta,
                               accuracy, @"Latitude delta is equal");
}

- (void)testMKCoordinateRegionForSouthWestAndNorthEast
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D taipeiWanHua = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.02946, 121.49652);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D taipeiSongShan = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.06640, 121.56166);

    /* When the following line is called, the first test fails */
    MKCoordinateRegionForSouthWestAndNorthEast(taipeiWanHua, taipeiSongShan);

   /* I have the rest of the lines in this test commented out */
}
```

Now, I have empty setup and teardown for this test class. When I run the test. The first test fails if the third line of the second test is in the test. A closer look shows that when it fails, it's that the values are still similar but falling outside of the given accuracy:
[image]

If I commented that third line of the second test out, the first test would pass. Why is that?

Comment: BTW, same thing happens even when I only run the first test. =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with unit testing - for me it fails even if I comment out entirely the second test - it is with the MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion implementation.
I think the correct implementation is:

```
MKMapRect MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(MKCoordinateRegion region)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = region.center;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = region.span;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeft =
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude + span.latitudeDelta / 2.0,
                               center.longitude - span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
    CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRight =
    CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(center.latitude - span.latitudeDelta / 2.0,
                               center.longitude + span.longitudeDelta / 2.0);
    MKMapPoint mapPointTopLeft = MKMapPointForCoordinate(topLeft);
    MKMapPoint mapPointBottomRight = MKMapPointForCoordinate(bottomRight);
    double width = mapPointBottomRight.x - mapPointTopLeft.x;
    double height = mapPointBottomRight.y - mapPointTopLeft.y;

    MKMapRect ret = MKMapRectMake(mapPointTopLeft.x, mapPointTopLeft.y, width, height);
    return ret;
}
```

check out this:  [Mercator Projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection)

Comment: For me it doesn't fail when I comment out the third line of the second test. I do not know but suppose my implementation is incorrect, it still doesn't explain why commenting the second test effect the results of the first test?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the first test, comment out that line in the second test, and check out manually what happens in the first test. Does it run? The values in the derivedRegion are okay? Just to be sure that in this case everything is okay.

Comment: Just one other thing, `topLeft`, and `bottomRight` are same in your implementation, which is clearly a copy-paste error ...

Comment: I couldn't get it to build when I tried to include an application target so I had to create a new project and put everything back. So I couldn't figure out what happened. But your code works, thank you so much.